# Strange controller error after upgrading from symfony 3.0.9 to 3.1.3

Tags: exception, controller, request, upgrade, symfony

I have a very strange problem with my Symfony application. Everything is working fine on symfony 3.0.9, but when upgrading to 3.1 (currently running 3.1.3) I get the following error with almost all Controllers:

> "Controller "Name_of_Controller::name_of_method" requires that you
>   provide a value for the "$request" argument (because there is no
>   default value or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one)."

Here is an example of a method that causes this error:

```
/**
 * This method handles add faculty
 * requests
 *
 * @param Request $request html request
 *
 * @return Response html response
 *
 **/
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    // create a new Faculty
    $faculty = new Faculty();
    $faculty->setFirstname('Enter First Name');
    $faculty->setLastname('Enter Last Name');

    $form = $this->createForm(FacultyType::class, $faculty);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $task = $request->get('Submit');

        // let see what the user wants
        switch ($task) {
            case 'Add':
                // user wants to add
                // we are setting the fullname of the object
                $lname = $form->getData()->getLastname();
                $fname = $form->getData()->getFirstname();
                $faculty->setFullname("$lname, $fname");

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($faculty);
                $em->flush();

                // report success
                $this->addFlash('success', "The faculty member $faculty was successfully saved!");

                return $this->redirectToRoute('faculty_index');

                break;

            case 'Cancel':
                // report failure
                $this->addFlash('failure', "The action was cancelled. No faculty member was saved!");

                return $this->redirectToRoute('faculty_index');
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        'faculty/add.html.twig',
        [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

The xml route for this method is as follows:

```
<route id="faculty_add" path="/add" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Faculty:add</default>
</route>
```

As mentioned above, it only happens on 3.1, the whole app works fine on 3.0.9.

Anybody else seen this? Do I have a structural problem in my code that was unveiled in 3.1 (I am not a professional coder...)

thanks!

Andreas

Comment: Have you cleared the cache since upgrading?  Is Request properly namespaced? Maybe update your question with the route definition.  The cache clearing is the only thing that might cause the problem.

Comment: Try clean your cache. `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: yep. done all that. I have found something else that might be of interest. The problem disappears when running symfony ^3.1 with php7.0. The problem only occurs with symfony > 3.0 on php > 7.0.

Comment: I think you can report it on Github :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer, but might be helpful for those other hobby coders out there that have a similar problem:

The problem disappears when using php7.0 instead of 7.1. The same is true when running symfony 3.0.x on php 7.1.

It only persists when using both php 7.1 and symfony 3.1. 
As I tried both dev and prod environments, emptied the cache repeatedly and could reproduce this both on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet and my MacBook Pro, I can't imagine it is a caching issue.

Not sure whether this is a true bug or there is something in my code that causes this problem.

I'll update this should I find a more definitive cause for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

I have finally found the cause of the problem (for me): there was a typo in:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

(a lowercase letter instead of an uppercase letter). Strange thing: it had been working for years with all the Symfony/PHP versions (from Sf-2.6 and PHP-5.4) and it became a problem recently with the Sf/PHP versions mentioned below.

PHP namespaces are case-insensitive, but Symfony's resolvers seem to be sometimes case-sensitive...

**Previous answer:**

It seems that this behavior is due to the "ReflectionType improvements" feature in PHP 7.1: [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2068).

The consequences on Symfony have been reported on this issue: github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19677 (sorry, I can't create more than 2 links with my reputation...).

The feature has been reverted since then: [ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72906).

Comment: I still have the problem with Symfony-3.1.3 and PHP-7.0.10 as well as with Symfony-3.1.5 and PHP-7.0.11...

Comment: I now have this problem with Symfony-3.1.6 and PHP-5.6.24 as well as with PHP-7.0.12...